# Deleting tabs when using tabs as spaces

Tags: visual-studio, tabs, spaces, typing

I know that the general tabs vs spaces thing is as old as the hills and mostly comes down to personal preference/sticking to the style of your team, I just wanted to ask a practical question about using spaces in Visual Studio. There are certain things about tabs that bug me and I wouldn't mind changing to spaces while we're a small team. It would be no different for writing the code in the first place but would mean you'd have to delete/backspace 4 times where I'd previously press it once.

Is there any easy way of deleting tab sized amounts of spaces easily (other than dragging with the mouse etc.) or if you've gone through the changeover yourself is it something that eventually doesn't bother you at all?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

In Visual Studio, use `Shift-Tab`.  This will go back one tab-stop, even when using soft tabs.

Comment: Excellent, I actually use this quite a lot already to change blocks of code, didn't actually know or think about what it did when there's nothing selected.

Comment: For a couple of years always use delete 'a lot' ... This info changed my life :)

In Visual Studio code, the same feature exists and it can be used.

Comment: @Forgotten Semicolon you save hours of my life! Thanks!
BTW Does anyone know good YT vid showing all not commonly known VS shortcuts for formatting etc ?

Answer (score 6):

I've been plagued by the same issue for years. Finally, I did something about it. Let me officially announce version 0.1.0 of the [TabSanity Visual Studio extension for VS 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ac4d4d6b-b017-4a42-8f72-55f0ffe850d7).

It doesn't just stop at backspaces. It handles the delete key as well as arrow key navigation. Mouse interactions planned for near-future development.

There are some minor bugs I still need to resolve, but the groundwork is laid and I'm making steady progress. It's an open source project, so feel free to [contribute on GitHub](https://github.com/jedhunsaker/tabsanity-vs).

Comment: FWIW, vscode now has this feature mostly baked in.

Comment: I found a fork of your project, made by pragmatrix that has been updated for vs2022 -- I compiled and uploaded the vsix here for anyone interested: [tabsanity-2022.vsix](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KHO-PvgACPz_VpCnV9l0DRUFtAZgohyR/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015

1. Open file.
2. Select all lines you wish to modify (or CTRL+A for entire file).
3. Choose Edit->Advanced->"Untabify selected lines"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy answer to this problem. I use Xcode and Visual Studio, and both have really annoying indentation. Maybe there's an option to disable autoindentation altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there's a very easy way.
You set your Visual Studio options (Tools/Options/Text Editor) to use spaces instead of tabs and then you open a source file and Ctrl-E,D (Edit/Advanced/Format Document) and it will convert them all for you!

Yay for automation!

Comment: This is a neat trick; unfortunately it also takes care of all the "other" formatting as well ;-)

Comment: "other" formatting?  I can't currently think of more than one kind of formatting...