# How to make backspace behave as backspace in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code I indent using two manually inserted blanks. When I press backspace this deletes two blanks at the same time.

How can I turn off this behavior? I want a backspace to "eat up" exactly ONE blank, especially if the blank is a blank and not a tab.

The question is just the opposite to [Deleting tabs when using tabs as spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086289/deleting-tabs-when-using-tabs-as-spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) you can create a keybinding that does what you want

add to `keybindings.json` (at the end) this will overrule the default `backspace` behavior

```json
  {
    "key": "backspace",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "cursorLeft",
            "deleteRight"
        ]
    }
  }
```

**Edit**

Added  `&& !editorHasSelection` to get the default behavior when there is a selection

Comment: Works for me very nicely. For the keybindings.json I had to consult https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings because I did not know that. For the extension I used https://open-vsx.org/extension/ryuta46/multi-command and to get that into VS Codium I used https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/how-to-can-i-install-vscode-extension-on-vs-codium-with-code-examples/

Comment: Hm. Sorry. This does not work as expected. When I select several characters and press return I would expect the selection to be deleted with backspace. However, only one character is deleted. This is an undesirable effect. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog `and press return`??? you can create a similar keybinding with a `when` clause that also includes the selection test `"when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"`, place this new one after the one above

Comment: Works for me with `!editorHasSelection`. I need the negation of course. And I am turning into a codium fan. Thanx a lot!!

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog I was under the impression you wanted different behavior when you had a selection, you want the default behavior when you have a selection